# Unable to select ng-model after data source is read

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, dropdown

Have a very simple task that for some reason is not working. What we are trying to do is allow the user to create an object (in this case a filter), add it to an Angular drop down, and then set the drop down to that user created value.

Everything is working except the setting of the drop down. The response.data parameter has the correct value of the ID. In fact if we hard code this value into that line it updates the drop down. But trying to set this through a variable causes the drop down value to not be set.

Code below:

```
$http.post('<apicallurl>', filterSaveObject).
      then(function (response) {
          $scope.filtersDataSource.read()
          $scope.selectedFilter = {}; -- selectedFilter is the ng-model
          $scope.selectedFilter.ID = response.data -- this line causing issues
      }, function (response) {
          alert('At least one filter is required');

      });
```

My best guess is that the model is not ready and so that is why we can statically set it but not through the response.data call. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Adding code for drop down

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list ="filterDropdownList"
k-options="filterDropdownOptions"
k-data-source="filtersDataSource"
k-ng-model="selectedFilter"></select>
```

Comment: Show us the code used to create your dropdown.

Comment: Added an edit for this